# Escape hides complete UI

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I've upgraded to Eclipse Kepler from Juno, and I find that it handles the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key completely differently.

Usually, with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key I could abort smaller views/menus like auto-completion: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open the auto-completion dropdown, <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close it.

However, with Kepler I find that <kbd>Esc</kbd> hides basically everything. Before:

[image: State before pressing Esc:]

After:

[image: State after pressing Esc:]

<kbd>Esc</kbd> is not mapped to any function (it's not listed in the configuration under keys). Is this the default behavior now? Does anybody else have this?

Resetting the perspective doesn't change this behavior. I think it might have something to do with the floaty windows style. When I installed Kepler and started it up, I had to manually resize the inner window (containing all the usual views) to the size of the screen.

Edit: I can get the UI back if I click the small Java perspective button in the little menu bar on the top left side. The <kbd>Esc</kbd> functionality seems to be the same with all the views (focusing each view, then pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> does the same for every view).

Comment: I don't know the solution to this problem. But if you think this is a bug & not a functionality, you can report it to eclipse bugs support at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/.

Comment: Additional information: This should either Windows-specific or installed plug-in specific, as I couldn't reproduce your issue on OS X.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be Windows-specific, as I'm running Kepler on Windows (Win 7, x64) and I don't see this behavior.

Comment: So far, my hope is that I am missing some new functionality, and maybe this can be disabled.

Comment: That is what i said, wtf is going on.  What kind of UI enhancement is this.

Comment: Doesn't happen for me on Win 8 64bit.

Comment: Did you try deletting the `.metadata` folder on your workspace?

Comment: this has been driving me INSANE :(

Answer (score 2):

Somehow what's happened is that you've managed to minimize your perspective *stack* (that's the bar that appears on the left side in your 'after' image). Usually this only happens when you open the 'Welcome' view (which is defined as being outside any perspective).

To restore it you just have to click on the 'restore' (topmost) item on the left bar.

Now as to why this happened as a result of hitting ESC I can only echo the suggestions from above about checking if some command has been bound to ESC (doesn't happen on my Win7 box).

Answer (score 0):

This poor perspective behavior is due to corruption in the workspace.

One of the following will clear it up.

**1) Attempt to repair the problem in the existing workspace.**

- Select `Window->Reset Perspective`.
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. (Does it work? if not read on...)

NOTE: Reset perspective restores the perspective to its default layout, thus you will have to re-layout your views assuming the default layout is not to your liking. Once you do so, however, you can save your custom layout using `Window->Save Perspective As...`

- After the perspective has been reset, exit and restart Eclipse to ensure the changes to the perspective are committed and stored properly to the workspace. (Try again, does it work? if not read on...)

As *Gunanaresh* mentioned in his comment below. It may be worth trying to delete the .metadata directory in your workspace. However, be warned this may not be safe! Back up your workspace prior to doing this. Better yet, try 2. first.

**2) Recreate the workspace.**

- `File->Export, Choose General>Preferences` to save your workspace preferences
- `File->Export, Choose Team->Team Project Set`. Walk through the wizard and export all projects. We will use the psf file to import projects into the new workspace
- Exit Eclipse.
- Start Eclipse using a new workspace.
- `File->Import, Choose Team->Team Project Set`. Point to the psf file you create and import your projects.

The perspective should operate properly now!

Comment: As I already specified above, resetting the perspective didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: After resetting, exit and restart Eclipse to ensure your changes to the perspective are committed properly to the workspace. It may also be worth trying with a new workspace.

Comment: Yes, eventually that's what I kinda did. I had to delete the .metadata folder under my workspace, and then launched Eclipes (now it won't show any project). Then if I click the Restore icon, it works.

Comment: Thanks Gunanaresh. I updated my answer. I also included the findings in your comment above