# Eclipse escape button binding

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

Further to: [Escape hides complete UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724947/escape-hides-complete-ui/19755648#19755648)

I have the exact same problem as described here... driving me nuts. Fresh installation on OSX Mavericks.

I've searched on the Eclipse bugs page to no avail.

Anybody?

Comment: Escape works as expected on my installation on Mavericks. Is there any binding for `Esc` in the Preferences > General > Keys?

Answer (score 0):

I've commented on the other post...the perspective stack has been minimized (did this happen on a fresh restart where the 'Welcome' screen shows up ?)